# Gradient fill of SVG path with Velocity JS

Tags: javascript, svg, velocity.js

Is there way to fill radial gradient as  `fill: 'url(#gradientID)'` using [velocity.js](http://velocityjs.org/#svg). Its no issue with filling single colors with animation as follows

```
$(event.target).velocity({ opacity: 1, fill: '#f60' }, 4000);
```

But not working for

```
$(event.target).velocity({ opacity: 1, fill: 'url(#MyGradient)' }, 4000);

<defs><radialGradient id="MyGradient"><stop offset="5%" stop-color="#f60"></stop><stop offset="95%" stop-color="#ff6"></stop></radialGradient><radialGradient id="MyGradient"><stop offset="5%" stop-color="#f60"></stop><stop offset="95%" stop-color="#ff6"></stop></radialGradient></defs>
```

How to solve above problem.

Comment: @RobertLongson I mentioned it on <radialGradient>

Comment: If your initial colour is RGB #FF0000 and you animate to #000000 then halfway is #7F0000, so animation from one colur to another colour is something that has a clear definition. If your initial colur is #FF0000 and you want to animate to a radial gradient, how do you think that should work? What are the intermediate steps in the animation?

Comment: @RobertLongson So how to define the steps?

Comment: You can't animate directly from a single colour fill to a gradient.  The gradient is either on or off. It's a binary state.  What you could do is change the single colour fill to a gradient where all the stop colours are the same. Then animate the stop colours to their final values.

Comment: You can however use standard linear-gradient css rules in Velocity...